# Cambridge A Level - Questions on Combinations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have learnt combinations and I have been attempting at these two questions but couldn't solve it:

> 1) In a mixed pack of coloured light bulbs there are three red bulbs, one yellow bulb, one blue bulb and one green bulb. Four bulbs are selected at random from the pack. How many different selections are possible?

```
I did 3C1 * 1C1 * 1C1 * 1C1 = 3
```

However, that wasn't the answer.

> 2) There are 20 teachers at a conference. Of these, 8 are maths teachers, 6 are history teachers, 4 are physics teachers and 2 are geography teachers.
>
> Four of the teachers are to be chosen at random to take part in a quiz.
>
> In how many different ways can the teachers be chosen if there are to be at least two maths teachers?

```
So I did 8C2 * 18C2 = 4284
```

Which also wasn't the answer. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As regards the first problem, divide it into pairwise disjoint cases where you select $k=1,2,3$ red bulbs. Then, by using the ["rule of sum"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum), the number of ways is
$$\sum_{k=1}^3 \binom{3}{4-k}=1+3+3=7.$$
Here you can also enumerate the seven cases explicitly:  RBGY ($k=1$), RRBG, RRBY, RRGY ($k=2$), RRRB, RRRG, RRRY ($k=3$).

For the second one, consider the complement case when you have $0$ math teachers, $m_0=\binom{20-8}{4}$ ways, and $1$ math teacher, $m_1=?$ ways. Then the number of ways such that teachers can be chosen with at least two maths teachers is
$$\binom{20}{4}-m_0-m_1=\binom{20}{4}-\binom{20-8}{4}-?.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please explain why I wouldn't use the rule of multiplication in this case?

Comment: No I mean I thought I was supposed to use the rule of multiplication but you are instead adding. So could you please explain why you would add

Comment: @kimchiboy03 I am  using the "rule of sum" because i'm considering pairwise disjoint cases  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum

Comment: @kimchiboy03 See my edited answer. Are you able to evaluate $m_0$ and $m_1$?

Comment: Would m0 be 8C0 and m1 be 8C1?

Comment: @kimchiboy03 No. For $m_0$ you have to choose $4$ teachers among $20-8$. Try again for $m_1$.

Comment: So m0 = 12C4 and m1 = 13C4

Comment: Using the values of m0 and m1 gives me a final answer of 3635... which isn't the answer

Comment: @kimchiboy03 For $m_1$ use the multiplicative rule. You have to choose $1$ math teacher among 8, and $3$ teachers among the remaining 12.

Comment: So 20C4 - 12C4 - (8C1 * 12C3) = **2590**

Comment: @kimchiboy03 Yes, is this your correct answer?

Comment: Yes it is! Thank you once again!

Comment: The first question states that four bulbs are taken from the pack, which means it is not possible to select no red bulbs.  You seem to be counting selections of three bulbs.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig Yes, thanks. I edited my answer.